# Boolean Operation On Linked Selections

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm using the sapling tree generator which creates many branches as "separate objects" but in reality they are joined into one object (sapling uses curves which i then convert to mesh). I am able to select a vertex on a branch, do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and get a whole branch selected. That is what I mean by "linked object", a branch.

What I am trying to do is take all those branches and do a boolean type operator on each other to create one object that does not intersect itself. Or at least create many objects out of the branches with "Cuts" along the intersection. Is this possible?

[image: object with intersecting branches]

Comment: This might help: You can select the trunk instead with  Ctrl + L (use Ctrl + I to invert selection if you prefer the branches instead). Press P separate them by selection. Do the boolean operation. And then use Ctrl + J to joint trunk and branches into one object again.

Comment: it might be worth mentioning there are different branch levels, so trunk is 1, branch level 2 may have branches from there as well. so there could be many join operations to go through. There are some hundred branches that need joining. I need to try out what you suggested though and see how that works! Thank you!

Comment: Ah, okay. : )  In that case I would select the tree, press P > separate by loose parts. Then activate the Bool Tool add-on in Preferences > Add-ons. It will then be located in the 3D Viewport > Sidebar > Edit tab. Select all your separated objects (and the trunk last just in case, so it has a yellow outline instead of orange) and click the Union button under Auto Boolean. I tried it (and it works) with cubes so i think it worth a try.

Comment: I think we are getting somewhere, but perhaps i did something wrong. There are many branches including the trunk that are now missing after the union operation. I will play around with the selections of branches.

Comment: I tried it with the default Sapling Tree Gen tree. (and on second thought i think the order of selection before the operation is not important) Blender froze up for a moment after clicking the Union button, but after a while it yielded the expected result. I can't say the topology where the branches meet is pretty, but it should work as i described it. (although you never know with boolean, especially from before Blender 2.9). In any case, i hope it'll work for you. good luck.

Comment: My apologies, on closer inspection i did find some missing branches. Maybe Union joining them in a few separate batches might work.